# Grant Select for users from a table?

Tags: mysql, view, sql-grant

is it possible to grant view permissions for a list of users who exist in a table?

I have a view MY_VIEW
and I have a pool of `USER`s. 
Some `USER`s are in a table `HAS_PERMISSION(NAME , ID)`
Some `USER`s are in a table `NO_ACCESS(NAME, ID)` .

There is no crossover, and the list of rows in each table may increase or decrease over time. I tried something like:

```
GRANT SELECT ON MY_VIEW TO
(SELECT PERSON FROM HAS_PERMISSION WHERE NAME = USER) ;
```

But I am being told `ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00987: missing or invalid username(s)`

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work. If that did anything, it would just be giving MySQL users permission. However your people, hopefully, do not connect directly to the database, but instead use an application you built which has it's own user (which shouldn't be root/admin). Your application should check the permissions for a user and decide whether or not that person can access the page in your application where the view is used.

Comment: Damn, thanks. Thankfully it's a fictional program. I'm going to have to write something into the view's select statement body itself which gives access to someone who is the user if they match with their correct table.